# How to use jhipster spring-controller spring-service with automatic options?

Tags: jhipster

Dear JHispter community,

is there a way to add options after jhipster spring-controller and jhipster spring-service to automatically generate the code.
for instance, jhispter spring-service is asking me: do you want to use an interface for your service?
how can i pass this answer directly on the command line, for insatnce

```
jhipster spring-service MYService -interface=yes
```

Thanks for your expertise.
Francois

Answer (score 2):

It is not currently possible to pass the prompt answer via a command line for the `spring-service` or `spring-controller` subgenerators.  It would surely be accepted in a pull request if anyone were to add it.

You can see the available command line options by using the `--help` flag

```
jhipster spring-service --help

...
Options:
  -h,   --help          # Print the generator's options and usage
        --skip-cache    # Do not remember prompt answers             Default: false
        --skip-install  # Do not automatically install dependencies  Default: false
...
```